# How to force PyQt button work in oop style program

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt, maya

Button looks right when i open pyqt window, but it doesn't do anything when pressed. How can i fix this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os, sip, sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

from .ui.gui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent,QtCore.Qt.Tool)
        self.initUI(self)


def show():    
    # Use a shared instance of QApplication
    import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    # Get a pointer to the maya main window
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    # Use sip to wrap the pointer into a QObject
    win = sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QObject)
    form = MainWindow(win)
    form.show()
```

---

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class Ui_MainWindow():

    def initUI(self, MainWindow):

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.btnQuit = QtGui.QPushButton("x", self)       
        self.panel = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)   
        self.panel.addWidget(self.btnQuit)       
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(self.doIt)      

    def doIt(self, MainWindow):
        print "DO IT!"
```

Comment: Do you actually have a terminal visible where the print statement "DO IT!" would appear?

Comment: yes i have, and it's printed when i for example define doIt function outside the class.